# WatiN KeyPress and keyDown events not doing anything on SelectList

Tags: watin, keypress, selectlist

I'm getting started coding tests using watiN and I'm having trouble simulating a user pressing a key when a SelectList is in focus. This is to test that a client-side JavaScript function that is triggered by the OnKeyUp event on the SelectList runs correctly.

How can I simulate a user giving focus to the SelectList and pressing the 'o' key on their keyboard?

I'm using the latest WatiN release and am doing a C# unit test in VS2008. I've coded

```
ie = new IE(myTestPageURL);
SelectList mySelect = ie.SelectLists[0];
mySelect.Focus();
mySelect.KeyPress('o');
Assert.IsTrue(mySelect.SelectedItem != null);
```

My select list has an option in it called "One", so pressing the 'o' key should result in it being the selected item. However, nothing is happening when the keyPress call is made except that the SelectList loses focus, and my test fails.

Comment: I actually require a key to be pressed in my test. The test is to confirm that a JavaScript function that runs when the user gives focus to the SelectList control and presses a key runs correctly. If it's correct, a certain option in the SelectList will be the selected item. Using SelectByValue doesn't achieve that. Incidentally, I have also experimented with System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("o"); instead of the mySelect.KeyPress call. It still results in no SelectedItem on the SelectList control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have, but have you looked into

```
SelectList.SelectByValue
```

?

It would,seemingly, make your tests more repeatable since you could add anything to your list and have it still work.  Also, your tests should still break if your selectlist items fail to populate (for whatever reason).  Selecting by value adds more specificity to your tests rather than just having them select the first item beginning with 'o'.

Fwiw is what we use in production at my current place of employment.

Answer (score 0):

I use `SelectList.Select()` to select my dropdown items.

But since you want to test the javascript event, you might want to try to explicitly invoke the javascript event with `Element.FireEvent()`.

Also, the `TextField` object has a `TypeText()` method that simulates a user typing and triggers all the events involved, but I didn't see a `TypeText` for `SelectList`.  Maybe you can find a solution with the two.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gram. Using Element.FireEvent works for me. For anyone who's interested, the code ended up looking like this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void KeyboardSelection_OptionMatches()
{
    ie = new IE("http://localhost:7561/WebSite2/Default.aspx");
    SelectList mySelect = ie.SelectLists[0];
    mySelect.Focus();
    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add("charCode", ACharCode); //Constant for test - equals '65'
    nvc.Add("keyCode", ACharCode);
    // this should select the "A" option
    mySelect.FireEvent("onkeydown", nvc);
    // this should move the selected option to "aardvark"
    mySelect.FireEvent("onkeydown", nvc);
    string selectedValue = mySelect.SelectedItem.ToLower();
    ie.Close();
    Assert.AreEqual(selectedValue, "aardvark");
}
```

}

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, could you please mark this as the correct answer? This will help other users resolve the same problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a calendar control and resolved it by invoking the .Blur() method/event on the control.